# Writable access for all users in fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, automount

What should I change in this line so every user can have writable access: `curlftpfs#root:12345@192.168.1.226/mnt/usbmounts/sda3 /media/MediaPlayer fuse rw,uid=1000,umask=0777,user,suid,allow_other,exec,auto,utf8  0   1`

Comment: Sorry for frequent question. I removed uid=1000 and all work better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other readers:  fstab (all lowercase) stands for File System TABle, and is a file located in directory /etc (short for etcetera), so its path and name together are /etc/fstab.  This is a text file, so easily read and changed with a text editor like gedit or nano, two of the most popular, because they are easy to work with.

Each line in /etc/fstab has a purpose.  They identify the device, by designation or UUID, its mount point, its type, its options (separated by commas), dump, and pass.  The lines below the labels are one device per line.  Spaces between fields are necessary, but the number can vary, do the fields do not necessarily line up under the column headers.  They just have to be in the right order, from left to right.

To change the contents, you have to have root privileges.  This means using the `sudo` command.  Research that one online if you want more info on  how to use it.  For more details on what you can do with /etc/fstab, do a 
search on fstab options.  Internet search with a search engine like google or bing and look for fstab options.  For what uid= is or does, I searched myself using fstab uid and found this linK:  https://superuser.com/questions/430707/how-do-i-configure-fstab-so-that-a-partition-can-be-used-by-different-users-simu

For your information, uid is short for UserID.  If it is there, it gives ownership of that device to one person,  If you had a gid= instead, it gives ownership of that device to one group and members of that group.  A gid=1000 makes more sense than uid=1000.  Getting rid of both means anybody that logs in can access the device,  But every folder and file has its own permissions settings, which still keeps your preserved content from being seen or used by others unless that is what you want.

However, you are not completely out of the woods.  If someone gets `sudo` rights, can log in as root, or access your data from another install or boot process, say from a LiveCD or attached USB drive, they can access these devices via their own versions of /etc/fstab and root privileges.

To prevent this from ever happening, some people use encryption as a means of blinding others from getting into their own account's files. I say blind rather than block, because they are still all there.  You just can't make out what they say or do unless you have the decryption key to unravel the encryption process.

But what if you forget or lose the decryption key?  And of course there is a counter key, which is the encryption key.  You need both. Although with a simple binary method like XORing or switching the bits/bytes/words/quads around in a reverse direction way of doing things, the same key can serve both purposes.

What does a key look like?  It's any string of characters that does not repeat itself over and over.  It could be a quotation, a passage from the Bible, a poem, even a long irrational numbered sequence.  Like PI, but that particular one is probably overused.  But there are other ones. Take the constant e for instance.  This is an irrational number that is part of our natural world and has been calculated out to an incredible number of places.  Here is a page on the internet where it has been carried out to 1,000 places:  http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/e_10000.html.

Now suppose you searched for PI out to 1,000 places which you can find here:  http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/1000_places.html.

Now suppose you mingled one set of digits with the other set of digits and come up with something entirely different from what either was originally.  You could alternate picking a digit, add digits in the same column alignment together and follow that with "casting out nines", meaning add any carry back in.  4 plus 7 equals 11, so you,add 1 plus 1 and get 2.  That becomes the new digit for that position.

PI begins with 3, and e begins with 2, so what if these were taken as offsets into either or both tables?  After a few twists like this, the chances anybody would stumble on your method of coming up with a super long key would be greatly diminished. And all you have to do is collect both tables as files, run them through a program that works one against the other with rules that you devise, then stores the results where you alone know this is your encryption/decryption key.  Entering the key when you need it is just a matter of editing the file, doing a Select All, then a copy and paste into the encryption/decryption process.  If the 1,000 pr so digits is too much, cur off the excess at the beginning or the end.  Just as long as you commit the method of creating the key to memory, you can always do it again and again and get the same results.

Going from /etc/fstab to encryption/decryption seems like a huge leap, but it's all about increased vulnerability and what you can do to fight it  No encryption or decryption method is beyond reverse engineering, especially when done in computer code, but the matter of key generation can be beyond the vision and ability of anyone, unless they uncover your method of how you pick and link your sources for it together.

Comment: Many of the bricks in this wall of text are not really relevant to the question.

Comment: I have managed to work it, but... system not boots when mediaplaer is off. Please help me. I removed ftp from fstab. Unable to managed it work. It least I hant a script that mount ftp, automaticaly without password. May add something in cron and allow sudo to run some script/

Comment: I dream to work it as usb stick(media player ftp), but scipt should be fine to

Answer (score 0):

OP answered:

I removed uid=1000 and all work better now